# Electronic supplementary materials for scientific journals

Tags: journals, paper-submission, review-articles, latex

Journals require certain heights & widths for figures, however, since it's my first time preparing an article with Latex I'm facing some problems.

For example I have a total of 20 maps & I'm thinking of making a grid called (fig7) using Latex for each 8 pair of maps. When I supply 
high resolution figures with the final script do I need to combine each map that I use to make (fig7) in one figure called (fig7.eps) or do I just supply each map with its respective subscript (ex: fig7a.eps, fig7b.eps, etc)?

Comment: Journal requirements for submitting figures vary. If the journal you're submitting to doesn't make their submission guidelines clear, providing combined figures may be the most organized option.

Comment: @Harry thank you for your response.but Im aiming for journal in Springer as main target than Elsevier journal as second option...however i've check guidelines for multiple times but there's no mention to such problem as you can tell I have 20 different maps for the study region that make the independent variables for the study,and assuming I made them in layout of 3×3 or 3×4 that means I resize them terribly in 2 pages due to limited space of the article of course. Then going by your advice the supplementary high resolution figure would be very bad & unreadable  than the one in the article

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot tell for Springer or Elsevier, but a couple of years ago I published a paper in an IOP journal which contained a table with several diagrams.

I submitted the diagrams separately and included them in the table's cells with `\includegraphics`, as I did it preparing the manuscript. It worked.

Each journal has its own idiosyncrasies when it comes to LaTeX practices. When the guidelines do not provide enough information, my strategy is to first try submitting the files as they are, following my workflow, and if it doesn't work I resort to other solutions.

Comment: Ok I will I try your idea @Massimo ...i will flag your reply as an answer for the moment if there's anything new I will update the question.thank you Harry &  Massimo